# Error message when starting R3.0.0 and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I just downloaded R3.0.0 in Windows 7, 64 bit.

When I click on the R icon, R launches but with the following error and warning

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘modeltools’
During startup - Warning message:
unable to restore saved data in .RData
```

and when I try to start RStudio, it does *not* launch but says

```
The R session had a fatal error
```

Comment: You may want to simply reinstall RStudio. There have been a few people mentioning problems after upgrading, and a reinstall usually solves it.

Comment: I tried downloading RStudio again, but now, when I click on the .exe file it doesn't work and says it is not a valid Win32 application. The RStudio page didn't seem to have different versions for 32 and 64 bit machines.

Comment: Did you verify the MD5 value after downloading?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. It didn't show up as an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a screenshot of the current [home page](http://support.rstudio.org/help/) for RStudio support:

[image]

A simple reinstall should solve your problem. Do be sure to verify the downloaded file's integrity by checking its MD5 hash. I'm not a Windows user so I can't recommend any particular software in particular to do this. I guess a good starting point would be [Microsoft's FCIV](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) (read about it [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/software-tools/ht/file-checksum-integrity-verifier.htm) and [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/software-tools/ht/verify-file-integrity.htm)). But, I'm sure there are lots of GUI alternatives too.

At the RStudio [download page](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop) you'll notice that the correct MD5 hashes are listed, along with the correct file sizes.

---

As for your error about the .RData file, that sounds like a corrupt .RData file that should be deleted. Most likely, somewhere along the line, you clicked on "yes" when R asked you if you wanted to save the current session (rather than you explicitly deciding to save the session, and thus, giving the file a proper name). Since the file has a dot before it, you'll probably need to enable "show hidden files and folders" to find it.

---

Also, remember that after reinstalling R, you'll have to also reinstall all of your installed packages before you can use them! After you have R and RStudio back up running, try something like:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

to reinstall all of the packages you installed from CRAN. If you've installed packages from GitHub and other places, you would need to reinstall those manually.

Comment: I uninstalled R, reinstalled it, then re-installed RStudio and it now appears to be working.  Thanks!

Comment: @TylerRinker, I couldn't fit it in the comments any longer :)